# I am facing Invalid reCAPTCHA client id: when using Google ReCaptcha V3 in my react application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I am using Google ReCaptcha V3 for my react application. I am using a test version key. When the page is loaded, the reCaptcha appear properly in UI but in console getting error that "Invalid reCAPTCHA client id".

Site key provides from config settings.

My app.tsx code looks like:

```
return (
<Provider store={store}>
    <ThemeProvider theme={watchDogTheme}>
    **<GoogleReCaptchaProvider reCaptchaKey= {configSettings.reCaptchaKey} useEnterprise={true}>**
      <div className="App">
        {settings ? (
              <BrowserRouter>
              <TopNavBar
              pages={[
                { label: 'Home', path: '/sub' },
                { label: 'Poos', path: '/poo' }
              ]}
            />
            <AppRoutes />
          </BrowserRouter>
        ) : (
          <h4 style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>Loading...</h4>
        )}
      </div>
      </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
</Provider>
```

);

In Actual Page it looks like:

```
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const key = configSettings.reCaptchaKey

 /*START: recaptcha code*/
  const { executeRecaptcha } = useGoogleReCaptcha()
  const handleReCaptchaVerify = useCallback(async () => {
  if (!executeRecaptcha) {
  console.log('Execute recaptcha not yet available');
  return;
  }
  const token = await executeRecaptcha('SubmissionPage')
  console.log(token);
  logToConsole(token);
  setToken(token)},
  [executeRecaptcha]);
   useEffect(() => {
    handleReCaptchaVerify();
   },[handleReCaptchaVerify]);/*END: recaptcha code*/
```

Not sure why it throws such error

Comment: Please add more info, code examples, in order to receive more help from the community